# Python package installed but not importable

Tags: python-3.x, gdal, anaconda3

I recently installed the package gdal for geospatial data handling, with the help of anaconda navigator. When I type to my MacOS terminal 'conda list', it definitely shows that gdal is installed.
However, when I try to 'import gdal' into Spyder, or Visual Studio Code, it returns 'no packages gdal is installed'. I don't really know what to do for Spyder to 'see' this newly installed package into my base(root) environnement.

Thank you for any advices/help !!

Tried to install and import a package, but importation failed. Installation seems however successful.

Comment: There are three possible problems(sorted by likelihood): Either you have not selected the correct version of python, the package installation failed without you noticing, or the page name is different from the name you import it with(this can sometimes also happen)